# How To Initialize a Variable to Previously Allocated Memory?

Tags: c++, constructor, scope

I'm using C++, and am creating a `ex_stage` class (a SystemC module, if it makes any difference). In the header file for the class, I define:

```
public:
    ReorderBuffer ROB;
```

Where `ReorderBuffer` is another class I have also defined, which has its own constructor. I have defined `ROB` as a global variable for the `ex_stage` class so that it can be accessed from multiple functions within `ex_stage`.

However, I cannot initialize `ROB` until runtime as it depends on user-supplied values for some of its functionality. So, even though I define `ROB` as a global variable, I cannot initialize it where it is defined.

Normally, I would do something like this:

```
ReorderBuffer ROB(<incoming variables>);
```

within the constructor of `ex_stage` to construct `ROB` at the same time. However, since I have already defined `ROB`, I'm not sure if I am able to do that without causing issues.

Will performing an operation like this actually affect `ROB` in its original scope, or will it create a new `ROB` with a scope local to the constructor of `ex_stage`?

P.S. - Sorry if this is hard to understand please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: You can delay the initialization of an object by declaring it as a pointer instead. Consider using a [`unique_ptr<RorderBuffer>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) (from `#include <memory>`).

Answer (score 0):

When you want to initialize something global, you have to be careful about "[Global initialization fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order-on-first-use.html)". If i were you, i would use an [unnamed namespace](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/global-vars.html) to hide a global var pointer and have some global functions (just inside a named namespace) such as `InitMyGlobalVar()`, `GetMyGlobalVar()` to initialize and retrieve the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to initialize `ROB` when your `ex_stage` constructor runs, you might find a [member initializer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) useful.

Member initializers allow class members to be initialized in a specific way, as opposed to just having their default constructors called:

```
class ex_stage {
 public:
  ex_stage() : ROB(<stuff>) {}  // constructor that takes <stuff> will be called

  ReorderBuffer ROB;            // default constructor will _not_ be called
};
```